# How to create this shape? (Fire Hydrant)

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to model a fire extinguisher following this model (I'm practicing). I stopped at this kinda curvy shape that is extruded from the circle. I tried as many ways as I could think of but the mesh wasn't clean like the picture, if I add SubDiv, things get worse. Any approach to how to do this?

This is the model that I'm following. The black circles are the thing I want to create
[image]

This is my model so far
[image]

This is when I tried to SubDiv the mesh (it's really bad)
[image]

Hope I provided enough information. I'm willing to provide more in order to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a topology that seems to work:

[image]

[image]

A bit tilted:

[image]

Comment: The master of topology strikes back again…

Comment: @Chris I'm waiting for you whole geonodes solution!!

Comment: Yeah, would be easy, but the OP didn’t ask for it so my answer would be closed, as my 15307 deleted solutions before and i don’t wanna waste my time anymore….‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: plus this time you would be banned and cryogenized for 10,000 years  :/

Comment: Of course  I also wonder that you aren’t allowed to delete your own posts here anymore…I don’t know whether this is conform with GDPRS - I would say: No‍♂️

Comment: Thank you so much. The picture I posted looks more circular on its side (you can look at the fire hydrant picture on the right). Do you know how? I'll look forward to following your method first. It looks great!

Comment: oh yes my bad, maybe keep the same topology but pull the edge a bit so that it tilts the side. Also it looks like in your reference picture the cylinder is 64 vertices and not 32, which will make it easier